# what is the best to format numbers as money in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have column which is in int and float format. 
ex:10000
but i need to display this value in UI as money format with comma separation. i have written below code to convert it.

```
PARSENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(amount) AS MONEY),1),2)
```

EX: amount=10000
Result of the above query is 10,000

since the above conversion uses PARSENAME, CONVERT, CAST etc., i feel that some performance over head will be there, but i am not sure.
Is there any best way to do above operation? or this is good.

Comment: You shouldn't format data in SQL Server at all. Do that in the application.

Comment: @usr thanks.. is there any good reason why we should not do that in sql server? i have written stored procedure, in that i am using the above logic

Comment: Business logic and UI concerns are usually done in the application because T-SQL is an awful programming language and we have very good app programming languages these days.